# Отбросить приставку слова

Tags: python, nlp, pymorphy2, морфология

Мне нужно получить инфинитив слова и отбросить его приставку с помощью `pymorphy2`.
Я пытался найти нужную информацию в документации, но не нашёл (есть KnownPrefixAnalyzer, но ничего не написано про то, как им пользоваться. Очевидно, это внутренний анализатор). Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: какой результат вы ожидаете получить подав на вход слово "приукрасила"?

Comment: @MaxU, я ожидаю на выходе слово "украсить".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from pymorphy2 import MorphAnalyzer
from pymorphy2.units.by_analogy import KnownPrefixAnalyzer, UnknownPrefixAnalyzer 

morph = MorphAnalyzer()

def cut_prefix(word, morph=MorphAnalyzer()):
    analyzers = [
        KnownPrefixAnalyzer(morph), 
        UnknownPrefixAnalyzer(morph)]
    seen = set()
    word_lower = word.lower()
    res = []
    for analyzer in analyzers:
        parsed = analyzer.parse(word, word_lower, seen)
        if not parsed:
            continue
        tmp = parsed[0]
        res.extend(tmp)
        if len(tmp) >= 5:
            if tmp[4] and tmp[4][0]:
                return morph.normal_forms(tmp[4][0][1])[0]
    return res
```

---

тесты:

```
In [131]: cut_prefix("приукрасила")
Out[131]: 'украсить'

In [132]: cut_prefix("подловил")
Out[132]: 'ловить'

In [133]: cut_prefix("мегаабракадабра")
Out[133]: 'абракадабра'

In [134]: cut_prefix("перенедоел")
Out[134]: 'недоесть'

In [140]: cut_prefix("безопасный")
Out[140]: 'опасный'

In [141]: cut_prefix("безобразие")
Out[141]: 'образие'
```

Comment: Спасибо. Можно задать два вопроса?
1) Зачем нужен входной параметр `word`? Имеет ли он какой-то смысл?
2) При каких условиях проверка `if len(tmp) >= 5:` не срабатывает? Разве такие условия существуют?

Comment: @user263096, вы наверное имели ввиду параметр “morph”? Если создать объект “morph” вне функции и передавать его в качестве параметра, то функция должна работать немного быстрее, т.к. не придётся вызывать конструктор для каждого вызова функции.

Comment: @user263096, по поводу второго вопроса - не знаю, надо проверять...

Comment: я имею ввиду первый первый аргумент `word` для функции `analyzer.parse`. Я проверил код и там этот параметр вообще не используется. Видимо, его можно опустить.

Comment: @user263096, не совсем понимаю о чем вы... Все три параметра у `analyzer.parse()` - обязательные и даже если какой-нибудь из них не используется их все равно придется передавать. Не понимаю как их можно опустить...

Comment: Я имел ввиду то, что мне можно в качестве параметра `word` можно передавать любой значение и не заботиться о том, что оно неверное. Это может пригодиться при создании одно строчного кода, например.

Comment: @user263096, а в чем выигрыш если мы пользуемся функцией обёрткой?

Comment: Да... логично. Выигрыша нет...

Comment: при выполнении функции вылезает ошибка:

 'KnownPrefixAnalyzer' object has no attribute 'get_prefixes'